# "Access Is Denied" Error In Python PyGame

Tags: python, cmd, pygame, command-prompt

[image]

I don't know if i can get a higher quality image, but i don't understand why this is happening.

I typed this into CMD:

```
pip install pygame
```

I have no idea if i'm somehow doing this incorrectly, can someone help?

I am really new to python and all this, so doing something wrong is a very high possibility.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you don't have the proper permissions to write to the install directory. To fix this, you must run the command as root.
In Linux, simply use the `sudo` command like

`sudo pip install pygame`

If you are on Windows, you can run the same command on an elevated command prompt windows by right clicking on the start button on the bottom left and selecting Command Prompt (Admin). Anything you run in this window will be run with administrator privileges giving you access to the install directory. Running `pip install pygame` should now work.

Answer (score 0):

That means you don't have permission to write to that location. Try running it as an administrator. If possible however, the correct way is to open a virtualenv and then install it there so that your system files are protected from any unintended modifications.